# Gradle/Spock/Geb org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: selenium, gradle, spock, geb

I have a gradle script which sets the geb.build.baseUrl to be a project property. This also does not work with a static url.

This works fine on Windows, but on Linux I'm having the following issue:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException at LoginTest.groovy:9
>           Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException at LoginTest.groovy:9
>       org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
>           Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException

When run a blank browser window is opened and the URL is not entered:

**Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    testCompile.transitive = true
}

dependencies {

    def gebVersion = "0.10.0"
    def seleniumVersion = "2.43.1"

    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"

    // Need a driver implementation
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.43.1"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.43.1"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"
}

test {
    systemProperties "geb.build.reportsDir": "$reportsDir/geb"
    systemProperties "geb.build.baseUrl": project.url
}
```

**Spock**:

```
package xx.xx;

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class LoginSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "login"() {
        when:
            to Login
            report "login screen"
        and:
            login(username,password)
        then:
            at Dashboard
        where:
            username   | password
            "X"        | "X"
    }

}
```

**Geb**

```
package xx.xx;

import geb.*

class Login extends Page {
    static at = { title == "xx"}
    static content = {
        usernameField { $("input",id:"pt1:it1::content")}
        passwordField { $("input",id:"pt1:it2::content")}
        loginButton(to: Dashboard) { $("span",id: "pt1:pgl13") }
    }

    void login(String username, String password) {
        usernameField.value username
        passwordField.value password
        loginButton.click()
    }
}

class Dashboard extends Page {
    static at = { title == "xx"}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When run a blank browser window is opened and the URL is not entered

From my experience, this is usually a symptom of using a Firefox version that is newer than what the used WebDriver version supports. I would suggest using [`selenium-firefox-driver` 2.44.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.seleniumhq.selenium%7Cselenium-firefox-driver%7C2.44.0%7Cjar) and if the symptom persist trying to downgrade Firefox.

Comment: At the time of replying my firefox browser was 36.0.1. I had to change the versions of the firefox driver and the selenium-support jar to 2.45.0